# No puedo acceder a mi carpeta de imagenes debido a htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

tengo un htaccess configurado en mi app, se supone que debe dejar acceso a directorios como el js y img, pero no lo realiza y no consigo solucionarlo. Aquí los códigos.

```
#Este archivo lanza la app, todo lo que reciba lo redirecciona al index de public
#Si se añade algo despues de eso se manda como parametro.

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On 
   RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
   RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Dentro de public tengo otro archivo más, aqui el código:

```
#Sirve para redireccionar directamente index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   Options -Multiviews
   RewriteEngine On 
   RewriteBase /Proyecto/public
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILEMANE} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILEMANE} !-f 
   RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Desde la carpeta app tengo otro también, aquí el código:

```
Options -Indexes
```

La petición de las imágenes las hago desde php, aquí un ejemplo:

```
print "<td><img src='".RUTA."img/".$img."' width='105' alt'".$nom."'></td>";
```

El archivo index.php donde se encuentra ruta:

```
<?php
//El archivo de inicio se encarga de cargar las clases necesariaspara el funcionamiento de la 
tienda
   define("RUTA", "http://localhost/tienda/");
   require_once("librerias/MySQLdb.php");
   require_once("librerias/Controlador.php");
   require_once("librerias/Control.php");
   require_once("librerias/Sesion.php");
   require_once("librerias/Valida.php");

?>
```

---

Por si sirve de ayuda la estructura de la app es asi:

```
Public_html/
  app/
    .htaccess
    inicio.php
  public/
    img/
    css/
    js/
    .htaccess
    index.php
  .htaccess
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a añadir las siguientes líneas dentro de tu archivo htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

Options -SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
```

Con estas líneas, permitirás acceder a las carpetas que mencionas

Comment: Acabo de probar y sigue sin mostrar las imagenes, ¡¡muchas gracias igualmente!!

Comment: Te da algún tipo de error o algo por lo que nos podamos guiar? Mira la consola del Navegador también

Comment: no no da ningun errror en consola, no se si puedo adjuntarte imagen de ella

Answer (score 0):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código desde consola aparece así,

Comment: Es mejor si pulsas en [editar] y editas tu pregunta, añadiendo la imágen ahí. Viendo esto, yo diría que el problema es que estás ecribiendo mal la ruta la imágen

Comment: eso creo yo tambien

Comment: No utilices las respuestas para agregar contenido, mejor edita la pregunta añadiendo todo lo que hayas encontrado o lo que te soliciten otros miembros de la comunidad.